# Calling lodash _.defaults() before Object.defineProperty()

Tags: javascript, node.js

In reviewing an older project of mine, I noticed that in a particular class definition I'm doing this:

```
var defaultOptions = { ... object of default options ... }

var SDKClient = function(options) {
    var self = this

    ...

    _.defaults(self, options, defaultOptions)

    Object.defineProperty(self, 'clientId', {
        enumerable: false
    })

    Object.defineProperty(self, 'clientSecret', {
        enumerable: false
    })
}
```

If I initialize the client object like this:

```
var client = new SDKClient({clientId: "x", clientSecret: "y"})
```

Should I expect there to be problems calling `defineProperty` *after* the property has already been merged in with `_.defaults()`? I don't see any errors or problems thrown when running tests, but this is a large project, and I can't be certain there isn't something obscuring errors. If it's not OK, why is it not OK?

Comment: I don't believe so [`_.defaults`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.0#defaults). The properties will be set on `this` but be enumerable. The call to [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)  will just set those properties to not enumerable. If the property didn't exist then the `value` would be set as `undefined`.

Comment: That sounds about right.

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving real/existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Comment: For what it's worth, this is concrete code, and it is being used in production. I left out impertinent details for brevity, but the intention is clear and my question is clear?

Comment: This is Code Review, not Stack Overflow. Brevity is irrelevant. We need to see your intentions to give the best possible advice.

Comment: Funny how Stack Overflow was delighted to mark it as off topic and suggest Code Review, since it's reviewing existing, working code.

Comment: Per our [help/on-topic], by asking for a peer review on this site you are *interested in feedback on any/all aspects of the code* - by removing chunks of context and boiling it down to a specific issue, you are funneling answers toward a specific area, which decreases the value of answers.

Comment: The advice given in comments on Stack Overflow can't be trusted when it's about Code Review. We've been fighting those since forever, unfortunately we can't catch them all.

Comment: So can this question be migrated to `stackoverflow` as it stands?

Comment: I asked a concise question and got a concise answer that resolved my question. I'm sorry it's not "on topic" according to the help centre, but maybe some consideration should be made for people asking for _code reviews_ on a _code review_ site with some leeway given when the rules of requiring all 921 lines of a class file aren't met. I can easily add all 921 lines, but they won't tell you anything different than what I've already provided.

Comment: Our standard is that you have to provide real code or an excerpt of real code. Changing the identifiers to make the question completely generic is not OK — that's what we call "hypothetical". Please read [ask]. The question should include enough context so that we can see what the code actually accomplishes, and the title should reflect the purpose of the code rather than your concern about the code.

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow users who recommend Code Review are unaware of the standards for Code Review questions, or neglect to mention it. We've created [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777) to help clarify the differences between the two sites. As it stands, the question is too non-specific to be a good Stack Overflow question, yet too obfuscated to qualify for a Code Review.

Comment: @200_success I literally copy/pasted this code from a _real_ project. To protect the owner, the text `SDK` was swapped in place of the copyright owner. This is real code, from a real project, that really executes. It is not hypothetical, given that before posting this here, I ran the project and its tests to validate whether the above would throw an exception. I then proceeded to explain exactly what this code does -- and you'd have to be an amateur not to be able to interpret from this tiny amount of code what is going on here. I have read both the guide for SO users and HtA.

Comment: What amazes me: 1) you could have left this alone; the combined number of minutes wasted on this pointless conversation is astounding. 2) I've read the rules; I'm aware of the rules; this is not, in my opinion, breaking them, because it is about **real, operational, executing, complete code**. 3) instead of approaching this from a "hey, this isn't so on the mark, but maybe we can provide some guidance", it was approached as "hey, I made an assumption about this and I'm right no matter what you say" by _more than one mod_. Don't you guys have anything better to do?

Comment: And frankly, I'm sorry that Stack Overflow doesn't like questions like these, but _they_ were here first, and that community is much larger and their rules are always going to outweigh Code Review's. Perhaps we should petition to rebrand this site as "Project Review" so that the ambiguous nature of the site never comes into question again.

Comment: Actually, if you mentioned _why_ you believe that there might be a problem with calling `defineProperty()` after `_.defaults()`, then this would be a fine Stack Overflow question. (Very sorry for the trouble, but the Code Review community has these rules to prevent "reviews" from devolving into speculation about what you really mean to do. Renaming the site to "Project Review" would lead to a different set of misconceptions.)

Comment: Sigh ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Sorry for freaking out. It's been a long day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so [`_.defaults`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.0#defaults). The properties will be set on `this` but be enumerable. The call to [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)  will just set those properties to not enumerable. If the property didn't exist then the `value` would be set as `undefined` and default descriptors.

Let's break out only the necessary.

Empty object.

```js
var x = {};
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x, 'clientId'));
```

Object with `clientId` set.

```js
var x = {
  clientId: 1
};
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x, 'clientId'));
```

Empty object.

```js
var x = Object.defineProperty({}, 'clientId', {
  enumerable: false
});
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x, 'clientId'));
```

Note that the default descriptors are set.

Object with `clientId` set.

```js
var x = Object.defineProperty({
  clientId: 1
}, 'clientId', {
  enumerable: false
});
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x, 'clientId'));
```

So if anything were to give you a problem then it would be this situation.

```js
var x = Object.defineProperty({}, 'clientId', {
  enumerable: false
});
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x, 'clientId'));
x.clientId = 1;
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x, 'clientId'));
```